# GPIO extra interrupt in STM32

Tags: interrupt, stm32, gpio

I see in STM32F103 series, the GPIO extra interrupt is set to the EXTI. And GPIOx_0 (x=A,B,C...)is set to EXTI0. Take an example, if I want to use PA0 and PB0 as interrupt input,can I set them to EXTI0 at the same time? I mean in the EXTI0_Handler function I read the value of the input register of PA0 and PB0 to judge which one input a electrical level I want to carry different function by using `if...else`. I use it in STM8 successfully but there seems a little problem in STM32. Can you help me? Thanks.

---

The answer explains the problem clearly. The picture takes an example that why the four bits will be changed if you set different pins. You can see that the four bit affect by each other status if you config other pins. I ignore this problem before.

[image: External interrupt configuration register 1 in STM32]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the STM32F103 [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf) p. 209, you will see that there is actually a multiplexer that decides if PA0, PB0, ... or PG0 is connected to the EXTI0 signal:

[STM32F103 ExtI0 schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKwcX.png)

That means that you **cannot** connect both PA0 and PB0 to EXTI0. In fact, there are four specific bits in the alternate function input/output register (AFIO) which let you choose which pin is connected to the EXTI0 signal. Here, these bits are located in the control register AFIO_EXTICR1. See the AFIO register map in the same document for further information.

Now I don't know which setup you are using, but as I recall, I had separate functions for different interrupt request routines (for EXTI0, EXTI1 and so on).

Comment: Yeah,just like you said, I read the Reference Manual before when I want to use interrupt. I know you mean that there is AFIO_EXTICR1 register to control which to connect. But can't we set all bits to set all to EXTI0, and then we use software query to check which line input datas? Take an example , Port A is set to EXTI0 in STM8s10x.And what I do is like that in intterrupt Handler function.
`if(PA_IDR_IDR0==0)  ...else if (PA_IDR_IDR1==0) ...else if...`
Do we have same way like that in STM32?

Comment: @mobiusStrip No, that wont work. You cannot set different pins to one EXTI

Comment: As I said, it's not possible to connect multiple pins to EXTI0.

Comment: OK ,thanks very much. I got it. I conceive that it can use like STM8 but failed many tries. I think maybe I config the NVIC wrong before. Now I know the different pins can't be set to the same EXTI. I should serch for a new way to realize check many keys input.